# Returning value based on column and index header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has index and column headers, like so:

```
 Customer ID     Email     Technique 1       Technique 2      ...
 12345           i@me.com  1                 0                ...
 ...
```

Is there a method that pulls the value with the corresponding index/column? In this example, the first two columns are indices and the first row is all headers. Does there exist some method such that:

```
 dataframe.method(index label, column label)

 dataframe.method('12345', 'Technique 2')
 >>> 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st set customer ID as index

```
df.set_index('Customer ID',inplace=True)
```

Then using `.loc`

```
df.loc[12345,'Technique 2']
Out[415]: 0
```